# php soap issue with xml format

Tags: php, soap

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
    <SessionIdHeader xmlns="http://www.inwise.com/webservices/v2">
      <SessionId>f554159f785d4793ab097470c7c76b2c</SessionId>
      <EndSession>false</EndSession>
    </SessionIdHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <Send xmlns="http://www.inwise.com/webservices/v2">
      <source xsi:type="MobileMessageSendingSource">
        <Message>
          <AccountId xsi:nil="true" />
          <Body>נסיון</Body>
          <Bounces xsi:nil="true" />
          <Charset>unicode</Charset>
          <CreateDate xsi:nil="true" />
          <EndDate xsi:nil="true" />
          <LastSent xsi:nil="true" />
          <Name>test for bt</Name>
          <NonSent xsi:nil="true" />
          <Opens xsi:nil="true" />
          <RecipientType xsi:nil="true" />
          <Sender>8858</Sender>
          <Sent xsi:nil="true" />
          <Status xsi:nil="true" />
          <TableConnectionId xsi:nil="true" />
          <Unsubscribes xsi:nil="true" />
          <UpdateDate xsi:nil="true" />
          <Validity>1440</Validity>
        </Message>
      </source>
      <target xsi:type="NewRecipientSendingTarget">
        <Recipient>
          <Id>0</Id>
          <MobileNumber>972506471313</MobileNumber>
        </Recipient>
      </target>
    </Send>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and this is what i'm sending:

```
 $paramsSend = array('Message' => 
            array('Body'=>'This is a test message',
                'Name'=>'FromBlind',
                'Sender'=>'7777',
                'Charset' => 'unicode',
                'Validity'=>'1440'
                ),
        array('Recipient' => 
                array(
                    'MobileNumber'=>'7849386874'
                    )
                )
            );
    $x['SessionId'] = $SessionId;
    $x['EndSession'] = 'true';
    $header = new SoapHeader('http://www.inwise.com/webservices/v2', 
                        'SessionIdHeader',
                       $x);
    $c->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$res= $c->__soapCall($module, array($params));
```

but they told me that the XML I'm sending it not the same to their XML,
I don't know what to do anymore, seems like everything's ok....

any advice's?

Comment: `$paramsSend = array(` and `$c->__soapCall($module, array($params));` why different name of arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't create a an xml like you posted above. So right what comes out from request is not in the correct format.

Actually the XML you posted is a SOAP message of invocation of the operation Send where you provide Message and recipient parameters but as said the don't respect the format of the SOAP message you posted. For example you are missing  field of recipient...

Try to build your paramsSend like this:

```
 $paramsSend = array('source' => 
                         array('Message' =>
                                array('Body' => "body value",
                                       'Name' => "name value")
                               ),
               'target' => 
                         array('Recipient' =>
                                 array('Id' => "id value",
                                        'MobileNumber' => "mob numb value")
                               )
                );
```

Remember to add the other missing tags for Message (Sender, validity etc)

Comment: Yeah I know, Now i'm getting: "source cannot be null" but I have no idea how to send the source...

Comment: Well when you build the message insert an array "suorce" before array Message. This way Message is an element of array source and you won't get the error. Also note you have to build a proper array hierarchies also to match the target->recipinet part of the xml you posted

Comment: I tried it 3 times and 3 times I'm getting the same error, I'm thinking it's because the 'xsi:type="MobileMessageSendingSource"' I need to set it somehow..

Comment: he is updated already... Again guys, please see the "source" tag... I'm getting always the same error "source cannot be null"... I need to send the source but there ix some xi:type I don't know what it is..